# Legend R: not printing some data

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a legend in R and I

```
dfk <- subset(df, df$V2 != -1 & df$V5>-50 & df$V5< 0 &  df$V6>-50 & df$V6<0)
plot(dfk$V5,dfk$V6, main = "1880 - 1 - 1/4", sub = NULL, xlab = "LON", 
     ylab = "LAT", ylim=c(-50,0),xlim=c(-50,0), 
     col = rainbow(length(dfk$V2))[rank(dfk$V2)], 
     pch=c(1:25)[rank(dfk$V2)],cex=2)
legend('topright',legend=dfk$V2[!duplicated(dfk$V2)],
       col=rainbow(length(dfk$V2))[ rank(dfk$V2)[!duplicated(dfk$V2)] ],
       pch=c(1:25)[rank(dfk$V2)[!duplicated(dfk$V2)]],
       cex=2)
```

and here the data

```
V2  V3 V4  V5    V6
16  1  2 -29.5 -10.5    
16  1  6 -30.5 -11.5 
16  1 10 -30.5 -11.5 
16  1 14 -30.5 -11.5 
16  1 22 -32.5 -13.5 
119  1 22 -30.5 -12.5 
16  2  2 -32.5 -13.5 
119  2  2 -31.5 -14.5 
16  2  6 -33.5 -14.5 
119  2  6 -31.5 -14.5 
16  2 10 -33.5 -14.5
119  2 10 -31.5 -14.5 
16  2 14 -33.5 -14.5 
119  2 14 -31.5 -14.5 
119  3  2 -32.5 -15.5 
119  3  6 -33.5 -17.5 
325  3 10 -32.5 -16.5 
327  3 10 -31.5 -17.5
325  3 14 -32.5 -17.5 
327  3 14 -31.5 -18.5 
327  3 18 -31.5 -18.5 
325  3 22 -32.5 -17.5 
327  3 22 -31.5 -18.5 
325  4  2 -32.5 -17.5 
327  4  2 -31.5 -19.5 
325  4  6 -32.5 -18.5 
327  4  6 -31.5 -19.5 
325  4 10 -32.5 -18.5 
325  4 14 -32.5 -19.5 
327  4 14 -31.5 -20.5 
327  4 18 -31.5 -20.5
```

The problem is that it prints out the legend with the three categories(16-119-325-327) but it doesn't print the data of the 327 category!

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is the the pch specification is not showing up in either the legend or the plot.

Comment: @user2287387: It's expected that you add a checkmark when you get an on-point answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 25 available `pch` symbols to chose from and the highest rank of `V2` is 27.5 so there was no match to a symbol. You could try dividing the rank by 2 and you will match to a `pch` symbol

```
plot(dfk$V5,dfk$V6, main = "1880 - 1 - 1/4", sub = NULL, xlab = "LON", ylab = "LAT",
         ylim=c(-50,0),xlim=c(-50,0), col = rainbow(length(dfk$V2))               
         [rank(dfk$V2)],pch=c(1:25)[rank(dfk$V2)/2],cex=2)

legend('topright',legend=dfk$V2[!duplicated(dfk$V2)],col=rainbow(length(dfk$V2))
         [rank(dfk$V2)[!duplicated(dfk$V2)]],pch=c(1:25)
         [rank(dfk$V2)[!duplicated(dfk$V2)]/2],cex=2)
```

Comment: Or shifting the numbers down by 3 or 4.